# how to determine if a semi-algebraic function has a semi-algebraic anti-derivative

Tags: calculus, first-order-logic

Is there an algorithm for determining if a semi-algebraic function has a semi-algebraic anti-derivative?  By semi-algebraic function, I mean a function that can be defined in a real closed field.  For example, such an algorithm would determine that $\;f(x)=x+7\;$ has a semi-algebraic anti-derivative, but that $\;f(x)=1/x\;$ does not.

Comment: Is *semi-algebraic function* different from: *piecewise algebraic function*?

Comment: So far as I know there isn't a difference.  Real closed fields have quantifier elimination, so any definable function should be piecewise equivalent to a function defined implicitly by a polynomial.

Comment: The interesting notion is "semi-algebraic set".  The case of semi-algebraic function (that is, function whose graph is a semi-algebraic set) has this more mundane description.

Comment: For Manuel Bronstein's book *Symbolic Integration*, volume I is "the transcendental case".  Since he did that first, I'm guessing that is the easy case... Too bad he didn't live long enough to write volume II, the algebraic case.